# How to sync edits for a file across multiple linux machines?

Tags: linux, rsync, file-copy, json, synchronization

I have 3 Linux machines which act as compilers to execute scripts in a parallel fashion. Now to make the execution better with less restarts of resources (where needed), I am developing a framework that holds a common resource and restarts it once when all the scripts that need the resource restart are ready together.

For eg: I have a CPU resource 10.10.10.10 that has to be restarted by 3 scripts on different clients. So, I am maintaining a common json file that attached the resource with script name and status.

```
common.json 

on client box 1
{
   test_one.py:{"IP":10.10.10.10, status:"READY"}
}

on client box 2

test_two.py:{"IP":10.10.10.10, status:"NOT-READY"}
```

So what I need is finally both sync and both enties get added to the common.json which will be on all the clients.

```
common.json
{
   test_one.py:{"IP":10.10.10.10, status:"READY"},
   test_two.py:{"IP":10.10.10.10, status:"NOT-READY"}
}
```

And after any update, like if NOT-READY gets READY then the client updates it locally and then same should get replicated on all the clients after that the restart command, I can trigger.

Please suggest some way, like rsync or any tool which can help fixing this issue.

Comment: Taking a step back from the file synchronization problem, have you considered using an orchestration tool (like Ansible) for this? You should then be able to manage the entire workflow from one system.

Comment: Hi @Haxiel, we wanted to keep things as simple as possible so Ansible has not been used until now. Can you please suggest how it can be helpful or if its possible to do this without Ansible?